# Can I automatically assign a page template to a custom post type (i.e page-slug.php file)

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template, post-type-support

I am making my first WordPress theme and I am trying to assign a page template to my custom post type automatically. (i.e page-slug.php)

As an example: you can make a page file in WordPress called *page-events.php* and then when you create a page called **Events**, it will automatically select this template to use instead of you having to go into the page and manually select the template.

I have made a custom post type '**Products**' and I want to make several custom templates files to use with this post type in my theme.

But I want to make the theme automatically select the template based on the page name like the example above. However, when I make a page called "**View Products**" and a template file called *page-view-products.php*, it does not automatically select the template for me.

Is there a way to make WordPress automatically select the template for the custom post type?

I tried naming the file *products-view-products.php*, thinking you put the custom post type in the file name, but that doesn't work.

To be clear, I want each page to have a unique template that is selected autmatically based on the page name, just like wordpress already does for the **Pages** post type.

I know how to manually select a custom template in the dashboard for my custom post type, that works fine. But I cannot find the answer for this question anywhere, so any help would be appreciated.

I am still a novice at theme development, but it is so fun!

Comment: **Product** is custom post type, so you should use `single-products-view-products.php` instead of `page-view-products.php`. More details you can find [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post).

Comment: Wow - that worked... I have been looking for this answer all over the place and somehow didn't find it. Thank you so much!